# Suggestion wanted: web-spider with Perl

Tags: perl, web-crawler, www-mechanize, lwp

The spider should:

1. Login via post a log in form
2. Maintain login stat by cookies
3. Follow random link in the homepage

The purpose of the spider is to keep a new website busy, simulating that many users are browsing it.

I had look at LWP and WWW::Mechanize. Not sure which module should use, or any other better suggestion. If you have code example is very good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WWW::Mechanize, between those two choices.  It has LWP::UserAgent under the hood.  I have no experience with the CPAN module WWW::Spider, and know that it's nowhere nearly as well known as WWW::Mechanize, but you may have a look at it too to see if it meets your needs.  I'd vote for the well proven option though.